# test express / express-session with supertest

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, supertest

I am trying to test an express api using supertest.
Problem arises when I am trying to persist a session cookie between test requests.
The stack I am using is express + express-session and supertest/jest for testing.
Using a simple logger for monitoring the sessionId.
Of course I am generating 2 different sessionId when testing using jest, since I am not saving any cookies. Getting the same sessionId when testing with curl.
How can I resend the cookie with jest/supertest?

**Server implementation:**

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
...

var simpleLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log({sessionID:req.sessionID});
  next()
};

app.use(session({
  genid: () => {return uuidv4();},
  secret: 'XXXXXX',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// login controller

const login = async (req, res) => {
  const {user_name, user_password} = req.body;
  const session_uuid = req.sessionID;
...

// login router
router.post('/login', loginController.login);
```

**curl test implementation**

```
curl -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt -s -w " %{http_code}" -X POST http://localhost:3001/login/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user_name":"xxx","user_password":"xxx"}'
curl -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt -s -w " %{http_code}" -X POST http://localhost:3001/login/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user_name":"xxx","user_password":"xxx"}'
```

**curl test logging (same sessionID)**

```
{ sessionID: 'fbc29360-1102-4d4a-81aa-961fa6810294' }
{ sessionID: 'fbc29360-1102-4d4a-81aa-961fa6810294' }
```

**supertest implementation**

```
describe('login endpoint tests', () => {
  it('ADMIN LOGIN', (done) => {
    request(app.app)
        .post('/login/login')
        .send({"user_name": "super", "user_password": "admin"})
        .expect(200).end(done);
  });
  it('ADMIN LOGIN', (done) => {
    request(app.app)
        .post('/login/login')
        .send({"user_name": "super", "user_password": "admin"})
        .expect(200).end(done);
  });
});
```

** supertest logging (different sessionID)**

```
{ sessionID: '0af83d6a-abaa-4fad-854f-1c3d627ab627' }
{ sessionID: '24d17bbc-1d6d-4192-9a7f-1b0b4a3fe5dd' }
```

Banging my head :(.
Any suggestion on how to persist the sessionID in the test?